# How to mention your rank about an exam you took

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request

How can I mention a rank you are at on an exam. Can I use the word "rank" to define a success on a exam?

An example sentence would be

> I was/ranked in top 100 out of 10 000 persons/people/applicants/test
>   takers on the exam.

Comment: I was ranked in the top 1% of those who took the exam.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your suggestion. Does it sound unfamiliar to refer to the numbers of entrants for an exam as in my draft example sentence.

Comment: Nobody will care about the actual numbers who took the exam. 1% is in the top rank regardless of how many there were.